# Framework recommendation request: Spring, Struts, Java EE?

Tags: frameworks, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, struts, presentation-layer

The last time I looked at web applications, the consensus seemed to be Struts/Java EE. Now, it looks like Spring MVC/Java EE or Struts/Java EE are both viable solutions.

Is this generally correct? Or is Spring MVC now the consensus choice over Struts? We have at least one guy who has worked with Struts before and wants to go with that. I'm more familiar with Struts as well, having reviewed it in the past.

Also, is Java EE still considered the viable solution for handling remote components? Or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real consensus for the presentation layer which is to me still a "throwaway" part of a Java EE application. The mentioned solutions don't suffer from big drawbacks or design problems and will do the job. I would just add [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/) which is a very elegant framework based on Convention over Configuration, simple and easy to learn if you have some experience with an action-based framework. And there is also [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), although Wick is a component-based framework which is a different paradigm.

Just pick one of them (the one you know the most seems to be a decent choice).

FYI, Matt Raible has done some nice comparisons of [Web Presentation Frameworks](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/11/raible-web) that are not totally outdated and still interesting. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

All those solutions are perfectly viable.  Unless you are just looking to pick up a new technology, go with struts since it's what you know.